# Cancel changes in last 24 hours in magento adminpanel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

At my work somebody that is not familiar with Magento did strange changes that affect my site badly,
is there any way to reset last changes.? As example: cancel the changes in last 24 hours

Comment: No there isn't a rollback facility in Magento until and  unless a backup is taken

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for your issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as a feature. You can however request a database backup from your hosting provider and overwrite your database.

Please note that all orders are lost as well in that case. A partial backup might also be possible where you leave the old `sales_*` and `customer_*` tables and replace the rest.

Also, make sure to always keep the `eav_entity_store` intact. The order increment ID is stored there and resetting that to a previous one will most likely cause fatal issues with your Payment Service Provider

Answer (score 1):

If you run backup everyday then it is possible.

Check your `var/backup` folder if you have any backup or else you can ask your server provider to see if they do everyday backup.

In dedicated server, server provider set `image creation` everyday, so that you can re-install server with that particular day's files.